# Azure DevOps Build publish does not include extra files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, msbuild-4.0

We have requirement to include extra files which are not included in the project because they are generated by webpack by different frontend project.

I have followed this article (https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/customize-an-aspnet-project-to-control-which-files-are-included-when-publishing-or-deploying/) and it works fine locally on VS 2019 when i publish but it does not work Azure DevOps Build.

Can someone please advise what i am missing ?

Update - 05/11/19

The below is folder structure of my source code

```
SolutionName
.... WebSite
.... FrontEnd
.... DataAccess
```

The "npm build prod" we run webpack and generate minified css and js in FrontEnd project and copy this to dist folder in WebSite and also copy additional scss files to website project.

webpack copy files code snippets

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'assets/images', to: 'assets/images' },
  { from: 'assets/icons', to: 'assets/icons' },
  { from: 'src/sass', to: '../theme-src/sass' }, 
  { from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss', to: '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss' }, 
  { from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss', to: '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss' },
  { from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', to: '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts' },
```

Website.csproj copy files for publishing.

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">

    <!-- Copy minified JavaScript & Css files -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFolderFiles Include="dist\**\*.*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(DistFolderFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Copy Sass files for themeing -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <ThemeSrcFolderFiles Include="theme-src\**\*.*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(ThemeSrcFolderFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>theme-src\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Copy Sass files for themeing dependency -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <NodeModulesFolderFiles Include="node_modules\**\*.*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(NodeModulesFolderFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>node_modules\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>

  </Target>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk i updated with details for pipeline and some code snippets. Let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: Why not try to using [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to pick up these generated files, then copy to somewhere which your next step need use?

Comment: I tried Copy Files and this adds folder to drop but it is not included in Website.zip so not deployed to server.

Comment: Not sure what's your project type? This  `<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn> </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn> ` works fine on my side. And I don't think any issue on your csproj file. How about using dotnet task to build your project?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am having the same issue

Comment: Two years later…Does anyone have a solution for this issue?